# Como puedo cambiar de sitio la flecha del JComboBox con `BasicComboBoxUI`?

Tags: java

Me podrian decir como cambio de sitio la flecha del `JComboBox`, yo ya he investigado mucho, de como personalizar un `JComboBox`, y de tanto investigar (4 dias seguidos) lo unico que encontre fue la libreria `BasicComboBoxUI`, pero ahora no encuentro quien la sepa utilizar, y yo he probado mucho pero, hacer las cosas sin saber si esta bien o mal, es dificilisimo, y recurro ahora a ustedes, que yo se que son mas expertos que yo y de pronto han querido al igual que yo personalizar un `JComboBox`, yo ya puse la imagen de la flecha como yo queria pero ahora quiero ubicarla en otro sitio, asi le puse la imagen al `JComboBox`

```
public class Propiedades extends BasicComboBoxUI{
  public static ComboBoxUI createUI(JComponent com){
    return new Propiedades();
  }

  @Override
  protected JButton createArrowButton() {
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/descarga.png")));
    btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    return btn;
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres cambiar de sitio la flecha? ¿A cuál sitio?

Comment: Pues la flecha aparece a la derecha pues yo quiero a la izquierda, porque? pues me parece mas bonito y pues es mas estetico, ( desde mi punto de vista)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es ubicar el botón del *drop-down* a la izquierda puedes hacerlo simplemente cambiando la orientación del componente:

`miComboBox.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`

De ese modo tanto el botón como el *scroll bar* de la `JList` que emerge quedan posicionados a la izquierda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ohhh amigoo graciass, mil gracias llevaba rato que lo buscaba wow